# How MPI assigns processes to CPU cores？

Tags: mpi, cpu-cores

If there is a CPU with 4 cores, I run "mpiexec -N 2 program", does the two processes run on same core or two cores? Who assigns processes to CPU cores, CPU or MPI? And how about "mpiexec -N 4 program", how many cores will be allocated?

Comment: This is implementation specific, and can be influenced by the resource manager you use (if any). Which library (vendor & version) are you using?

Comment: I use mpich-3.3.1. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I do not know MPICH enough, but if you run on Linux, you can `mpiexec -N 4 grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status`, it will show the allowed PU (core or yperthread) for each rank.